# Passing an array to NOT IN clause

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql, dynamic-soql

Apex:

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Topic> getFilteredTopics(List<String> notInTypes) {
        return [
            SELECT Id,Type 
            FROM Topic 
            WHERE Type NOT IN :notInTypes
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
            ORDER BY Name
        ];
    }
```

JS:

```
getFilteredTopics(this.topicTypes)
```

this.topicTypes in this case is an array that looks like: ['Basics', 'Other']

Can I not pass an array like this? The soql query works in the dev console when I run it like this:

```
SELECT Id,Type FROM Topic WHERE Type NOT IN ('Basics', 'Other') ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thanks for what you've included. Can you please elaborate on "Can I not pass an array like this?" i.e., Are you getting an error?, Are you getting unexpected results? Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/365487/edit) your question to add that additional info - including the *exact* error text for any error(s) you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is fine.

Parameters should be in Object notation:

```
getFilteredTopics({notInTypes:this.topicTypes})
```

The parameter names are case sensitive.